# SelectedIndex does not work on custom control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

SelectedIndex is always -1 even if in BookView count is greater than 0. And SelectedItem doesn't work as well, it's always null. I think it's something about the control, but I don't know what. Or is it possible the problem to be that I have to press once to expand and then I have to press the mouse again the update button to show the new window.

AdminHome.xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="BooksView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Expander Background="#e8f1f5" Width="700">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <view:BookControl Book="{Binding}"/>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

                                <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}"  Background="#27496d" Click="ButtonDelete_OnClick"/>

                                <Button Content="Update" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}" Click="ButtonUpdate_OnClick" />

                                <Button Content="More" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}"  Background="#70416d"/>

                                <Button Content="History" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}" Background="#420000" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

AdminHome.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class AdminHome : Window
{
    private List<Book> books;
    private readonly ServiceClient _serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
    
    public AdminHome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        books = _serviceClient.BooksList();
        BooksView.ItemsSource = books;

    }

    private void ButtonUpdate_OnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
                    var selectedBook = BooksView.SelectedItem as Book;
                    var UpdateBookWindow = new UpdateBook(selectedBook);
                    UpdateBookWindow.Show();*/


        if (BooksView.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            var updateBookWindow = new UpdateBook(books[BooksView.SelectedIndex]);
            updateBookWindow.Show(); 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("aassd");
        }

    }
```

BookControl.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class BookControl : UserControl
{

    public Book Book
    {
        get => (Book) GetValue(BookProperty);
        set => SetValue(BookProperty, value);
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BookProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Book", typeof(Book),typeof(BookControl),new PropertyMetadata(new Book()
            {Title = "Title",UniqueCode = "ISBN",Author = "Author",Editure = "Publisher"},SetText));

    private static void SetText(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BookControl control = d as BookControl;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.TitleTextBlock.Text = (e.NewValue as Book).Title;
            control.IsbnTextBlock.Text = (e.NewValue as Book).UniqueCode;
            control.AuthorTextBlock.Text = (e.NewValue as Book).Author;
            control.EditureTextBlock.Text = (e.NewValue as Book).Editure;

        }
    }
    public BookControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the `Expander` or `Button` doesn't select the `ListViewItem` that is "behind" the `Expander`.

You can work around this by creating an `ItemContainerStyle` and handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
private void ListViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)sender;
    BooksView.SelectedItem = lvi.DataContext;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="BooksView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Background="#e8f1f5" Width="700">
                ...
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```